# ¿Cómo mostrar un pdf mandando datos por ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

¿Hay manera de que pueda mostrar un pdf que me manda el back? Yo mando los datos por ajax para que el back pueda construir el pdf, pero no sé cómo abrir el pdf. ¿Hay alguna manera en la que, si el back recibe los datos, se abra en una ventana nueva para ver el documento?

Al pdf lo están creando con php con la librería de fpdf. En el código de php, cuando le meten los valores que yo mando por ajax, sí construye el pdf; no estoy seguro del todo si le están llegando los datos por ajax, según yo, sí... Pero necesito saber cómo mostrar después el pdf que se crea, poder verlo en una ventana aparte o verlo simplemente.

Les dejo mi código de ajax.
Y les dejo una parte del código de php donde construyen el pdf.

```php
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require '../librerias_externas/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require '../librerias_externas/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../librerias_externas/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

    require_once ("../db_funciones/db_global.php");
    require_once ("../db_funciones/db_usuarios.php");
    require_once ("../db_funciones/db_cotizaciones.php");
    require_once ("../db_funciones/db_log_movimientos.php");
    require_once ("../utilidades/funciones_utilidades.php");
    require_once('../fpdf/fpdf.php');

    // Realizamos la conexion a la BD
    if(!isset($backendIncluido)){
        $dbConnect            = comenzarConexion();
        $ejecutarDb           = true;
        $arrayResultados      = array();
        $objetoRespuesta      = array();
        $codigo               = '';
        $mensaje              = '';
    }

    // DATOS PEDIDOS POR POST
    $proveedor              = $_POST['nombre'];
    $folioCotizacionDetalle = $_POST['folioCotizacionDetalle'];
    $iva                    = $_POST['iva'];
    $firma                  = $_POST['firma'];

    $query              = mostrarCotizacionDetallePDF($dbConnect, $folioCotizacionDetalle);
    $folioCotizacion    = end($query);
    $folioCotizacion    = $folioCotizacion['folioCotizacionDetalle'];
    $fecha              = $query[0]['fechaRegistro'];
    $empresa            = $query[0]['nombre'];
    $atencion           = $query[0]['nombreCliente'];
    $telefono           = $query[0]['telefono'];
    $subtotal           = $query[0]['total'];
    $condiciones        = $query[0]['condiciones'];

    function obtenerFechaEnLetra($fecha){
        $dia= conocerDiaSemanaFecha($fecha);
        $num = date("j", strtotime($fecha));
        $anno = date("Y", strtotime($fecha));
        $mes = array('enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre');
        $mes = $mes[(date('m', strtotime($fecha))*1)-1];
        return $dia.', '.$num.' de '.$mes.' del '.$anno;
    }

    function conocerDiaSemanaFecha($fecha) {
        $dias = array('Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado');
        $dia = $dias[date('w', strtotime($fecha))];
        return $dia;
    }

    class PDF extends FPDF {
        function Header(){
            // Se utiliza global para utilizar la variable que esta fuera de la function Header()
            // Se hace una condición para mostrar diferente encabezado, dependiendo del proveedor
            // Proveedor SEGARED Header
            global $proveedor;
            global $dbConnect;
            global $folioCotizacion;
            global $fecha;
            global $empresa;
            global $atencion;
            global $telefono;
            if ($proveedor == 'SEGARED') {

                // Tamaño y fuente del texto dentro de la function Header()
                $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);

                // Membrete del PDF
                $this->Image('../assets/membretes/sega2.jpeg', -2,-2,301,214);
                // Mostrar los resultados de la consulta entre los recuadros
                $this->SetX(-62);
                $this->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
                $this->Cell(40,-1,'C O T I Z A C I O N',0,1,'C');
                $this->SetTextColor(41, 41, 41 );
                $this->SetX(-62);
                $this->Cell(40,15,$folioCotizacion,0,1,'C');
                $this->SetX(-62);
                $this->Cell(40,10,$fecha,0,1,'C');
                $this->SetX(-62);
                $this->Cell(40,15,'',0,1,'C');

                // Datos de abajo del logo
                $this->SetX(40);
                $this->Cell(220,13,$empresa,0,1);
                $this->SetX(40);
                $this->Cell(200,3,$atencion,0,0);
                $this->Cell(30,3,$telefono,0,0);

                // celda ficticia para dar espacio de línea
                // $this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
                // Esto equivale a:
                $this->Ln(15);
                $this->SetAutoPageBreak('auto', 40);
            }
        }
    }
    // Proveedor SEGARED
    if ($proveedor == 'SEGARED') {
        $pdf = new PDF('L','mm','A4');

        $pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        //define standard font size
        $fontSize=12;

        // Ciclo para extraer datos
        foreach($query as $item){
            $pdf->SetX(7);
            $cellWidth=150;//ancho de celda que hará el MultiCell
            $cellHeight=6;//altura entre cada celda
            
            //comprobar si el texto se está desbordando
            if($pdf->GetStringWidth($item['descripcion']) < $cellWidth){
                //si no, no hagas nada
                $line=1;
            }else{
                //si es así, calcule la altura necesaria para la celda
                //dividiendo el texto para que se ajuste al ancho de la celda
                //luego cuente cuántas líneas se necesitan para que el texto se ajuste a la celda
                
                $textLength=strlen($item['descripcion']);   //longitud total
                $errMargin=10;      //margen de error de ancho de celda, por si acaso
                $startChar=0;       //posición inicial del carácter para cada línea
                $maxChar=0;         //carácter máximo en una línea, para ser incrementado más tarde
                $textArray=array(); //para sostener las cuerdas para cada línea
                $tmpString="";      //para sostener la cadena por una línea (temporal)
                
                while($startChar < $textLength){ //bucle hasta el final del texto
                    //bucle hasta alcanzar el carácter máximo
                    while( 
                    $pdf->GetStringWidth( $tmpString ) < ($cellWidth-$errMargin) &&
                    ($startChar+$maxChar) < $textLength ) {
                        $maxChar++;
                        $tmpString=substr($item['descripcion'],$startChar,$maxChar);
                    }
                    //mover startChar a la siguiente línea
                    $startChar=$startChar+$maxChar;
                    //luego agréguelo a la matriz para que sepamos cuántas líneas se necesitan
                    array_push($textArray,$tmpString);
                    //restablecer maxChar y tmpString
                    $maxChar=0;
                    $tmpString='';
                    
                }
                //obtener el número de línea
                $line=count($textArray);
            }
            
            //escribe las celdas
            $pdf->Cell(5,($line * $cellHeight),$item['idDetalle'],0,0,'C'); //adaptar la altura al número de líneas
            $pdf->SetX(25);
            $pdf->Cell(5,($line * $cellHeight),$item['cantidad'],0,0,'C'); //adaptar la altura al número de líneas
            $pdf->SetX(38);
            $pdf->Cell(30,($line * $cellHeight),$item['clave'],0,0,'C'); //adaptar la altura al número de líneas
            
            $xPos=$pdf->GetX();
            $yPos=$pdf->GetY();
            $pdf->SetX(75);
            $pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,utf8_decode($item['descripcion']),0);
            
            //devuelve la posición de la siguiente celda al lado de la multicelda
            // y compensar la x con ancho multicelda
            $pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);
            
            $pdf->SetX(-72);//Recorrer fila manualmente de manera horizontal
            // $pdf->Cell(20,($line * $cellHeight),'$ '.number_format($item['precio']),0,1); //adaptar la altura al número de líneas
            $pdf->Cell(47,($line * $cellHeight),'$ '.number_format($item['precioUnitario']),0,0,'C'); //adaptar la altura al número de líneas
            $pdf->Cell(20,($line * $cellHeight),'$ '.number_format($item['importe']),0,1); //adaptar la altura al número de líneas
            $pdf->Ln(2);

        }
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    if(!isset($backendIncluido))
    cerrarConexion($dbConnect);
    echo json_encode(constructorRespuesta($codigo, $mensaje, $objetoRespuesta), JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
?>
```

```js
function imprimirCotizacion(e){
    var nombreProveedorImprimir = $("#empresaSelectImprimir option:selected").attr("empresa");
    var folioCotizacionImprimir = $("#cotizacion_imprimir option:selected").attr("folioCotizacion");
    var ivaCheckCotizacionImprimir   = $("#utilidad_cotiz") .val();
    // var folioCheckCotizacionImprimir = $("#folioCotizImprimir").prop("checked");
    var firmaCotizacionImprimir = $("#firmaCotizImprimir").prop("checked");
    // var nombreEmpresaGeneral = $("#empresaSelectImprimir").val();

    var jsonData = {
        "nombre": nombreProveedorImprimir,
        "folioCotizacionDetalle": folioCotizacionImprimir,
        "iva": ivaCheckCotizacionImprimir,
        "firma": firmaCotizacionImprimir
        // "folioCotizacion": foliosEmpresas,
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../pdf_cotizaciones/cotizaciones.php",
        data: jsonData,
        success:function(data){
            
            closeMessageOverlay();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para poner el código de `cotizaciones.php`, no es necesario que pongas todo, solo como armas el PDF y qué es lo que devuelve.

Comment: claro enseguita te muestro una parte del php

Comment: Aparentemente, envías como respuesta 3 variables vacías, código, mensaje y objeto respuesta.

Comment: Si entregas el PDF como archivo a descargar, el navegador se encarga de mostrarlo o de ofrecer la descarga.

Comment: @Alfabravo, y eso que comentas lo manda el back o lo hace el front o como se puede hacer eso que comentas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo estoy trabajando con pdf también, en el siguiente script lo que hago es hacer una petición al `backend`,éste último hace una query a la base de datos y crea un `pdf` hace un return del archivo y con este script lo abro en una nueva pestaña

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        try {
            //Obtenemos la respuesta para convertirla a blob
            var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            //Creamos objeto URL
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //Abrir en una nueva pestaña
            window.open(downloadUrl);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        ShowModalCargando(false);
        console.log("Error al intentar realizar el pdf: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Aca abajo te dejo documentacion de lo que uso arriba
[CreateObjectURL documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

[Blob documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob)

acá te dejo el algoritmo de lo que sucede
1.Hago una petición con `ajax` enviando un `id` (**frontend**)

2.El backend recibe el `id`, consulta a la base de datos (**backend**)

3.Crea un `pdf` con la información de la base de datos(**backend**)

4.Responde con un `pdf` creado (es la respuesta a la petición `ajax`)(**backend**)

5.`Ajax` lo recibe lo transforma y lo muestra en una nueva pestaña (**frontend**)

El código en el `backend` no lo muestro, porque **mi script responde a tu pregunta de como mostrarlo**, te aclaro que en el backend uso **c#**, pero eso no importa finalmente retornas un `pdf` y `ajax` lo trabaja, asi que el lenguaje o el framework que uses no debería influir en el script.
Espero te sirva

Comment: disculpa tu codigo que pusiste, tu creas el pdf?? o lo creas desde php y con ese ajax lo muestras??

Comment: Como explico en la respuesta, (desde el frontend) envio un id para que el backend haga una consulta a la base de datos, con la respuesta de la base de datos crea un pdf(el backend) y lo retorna como respuesta para que el frontend  tome el pdf y lo muestre en una nueva pestaña.

Comment: Edité la respuesta para ser mas claro de como es el proceso

Comment: muchas gracias amigo te agradezco la respuesta